# django m2m field return objects instead of keys

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model:

```
class Scenario(models.Model):
    tasks = models.ManyToManyField(Task, blank=True)
```

Its serializer:

```
class ScenarioSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Scenario
        fields = '__all__'
```

And a view to retrieve and post Scenarios:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def scenarios_list(request):

    scenarios = []

    """
    List all scenarios, or create a new.
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # get projects of a specific stakeholder
        if request.query_params.get('stakeholderId'):
            stakeholderId = request.query_params.get('stakeholderId')
            scenarios = Scenario.objects.filter(stakeholder=stakeholderId)
            serializer = ScenarioSerializer(scenarios, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            scenarios = Scenario.objects.all()
            serializer = ScenarioSerializer(scenarios, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = ScenarioSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(stakeholder=request.user)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(
                serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

This gives me data as following:

```
[{"id":1,"tasks":[1,3]},{"id":2,"tasks":[2,4,5,10]},{"id":3,"tasks":[2,5,6]},{"id":4,"tasks":[2,6,10]}]
```

I want to receive task objects instead of their ids. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Isn't it the idea of the serializer to return just the `id` of the objects?

Comment: I am not sure but I guess not necessarily

Comment: It just ocurred to me (reading the first answer below): do you want the `Task` objects represented as serialized data with their fields? I understood you question to mean `Task` object as in Python class instances.

Comment: @Ralf good point.  I assumed it to mean `JSON` objects, but could have gone either way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `TaskSerializer`, and then tell the `ScenarioSerializer` that it should use the nested serializer to represent tasks.  Something like the following:

```
class ScenarioSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tasks = TaskSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Scenario
        fields = '__all__'
```

**A note on POST data:**
A nested serializer uses a completely different pattern than the standard pk-based relationship.  This is especially true when writing data. For example, it is unclear whether a nested write should use `get_or_create` or just `create` for related objects.  By default DRF serializers don't handle nested writes.  Check out [the docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) for details on nested relationships including how to handle a writeable nested serializer.

Comment: Sweet!  Glad I could help

Comment: I have question though, in this case should I also have to modify my POST request to send tasks objects instead of their ids? Because GET works but POST started failing!

Comment: Kindly see updated question with POST method for reference, it does not reach inside `serializer.is_valid()` and throws BAD REQUEST error

Comment: You're right, I should have mentioned it in my response.  Your question was clearly about read, but in my answer I was using one of my own writeable nested serializers as a model instead of going to the docs.  I've updated my response.

Comment: What is the easiest way to handle this situation? Tune my request JSON data from frontend itself or modify my serializer on django part?

Comment: Up to you.  Both are viable options.  Depends on how you use the API.  Another alternative is to use different serializers for read and write, but that can be kind of an antipattern.